How do I turn poorly formatted HTML into an XML Object that I can use with an XPath in Power Automate?
I have a Power Automate Flow that I am using to ingest emails, and output information into Sharepoint. When I convert the email body which is HTML into XML and then use XPath to search for information, Power Automate gives me an error saying that the XML is poorly formatted.
Error:
Action 'Initialize_email_header' failed: Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Initialize_email_header' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'xml' parameter is not valid. The provided value cannot be converted to XML: 'The 'meta' start tag on line 2 position 2 does not match the end tag of 'head'. Line 2, position 70.'. Please see https://aka.ms/logicexpressions#xml for usage details.'.
Function I am using:
xpath(xml(triggerOutputs()?['body/body']), '//h2[contains(@id, "client_name")]')
Here is the de-identified beginning of the HTML that it is choking on.
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
            <title>Receipt 87612836123 from Redacted</title>
        </head>
        <body>



            <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
                <head>

                    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                            <title>Transaction #87612836123</title>
                        </head>
                        <style>(Took this out for readability...)</style>
                        <body style="background-color: #FAFAFA; max-width: 600px; width: 100%; text-align: center; margin:auto; padding: 0;">
    

End of HTML File:
                                                            </body>
                                                        </html>

                                                        <img src="removed"></body>
                                                    </html>

I have tried pulling out the body as a variable in a Compose action and operating on that. As expected, it made no difference.
I have tried converting the body to an html file, then ingesting that, but Power Automate says that it is a json object with multiple values and cannot turn it into XML.
I have also tried to figure out how to remove the Meta tags from the file, but haven't figured how to delete entire lines. I thought maybe I could use a Regex for that ('<Meta.*'), but I can't seem to find documentation of Power Automate supporting RegEX, only PowerApps.
I'm open to other ways to find values in an html email body where the body can be dynamic.

HTML and XML are very similar, but have differences.  There are parser for both HTML and XML and you do not want to use the wrong parser.  I do not see XML in you data.  You should never us Regex on either HTML or XML.  Regex is for Regular Expressions and both HTML and XML are not "regular".  The link you provided is for JSON to XML and I do not see any JSON in the data.  The Body is clearly HTML.  HTTP message can contain a lot of different types of bodies : images, xml, html, text, mime (one or more attachments).  You do not have a JSON body.

There are 2 nested html documents there. how does the html ends? including the end of both html documents: </body> ...</html>

@jdweng Like I said, I am open to other recommendations.

@LMC Added. Also I realized there was another body tag opening I hadn't added so I put that in as well.

You could try this Linux one-liner to get the inner html of the second body but it's not guaranteed to work in all cases. gawk 'BEGIN { RS="<[/]?html>" }{ if(NR==3){ print $0 } }' tmp.html

Use one of the tools listed in option #2 Use a tolerant markup parser to cleanup the problem ahead of parsing as XML of the duplicate link (How to parse invalid (bad / not well-formed) XML?) to first clean-up the HTML.  That Q is about XML but the tools will help with HTML too.

Your comment about poorly formed is getting everybody confused.  You have a standard html and can parse with any html xpath library : Try https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html
